# How to animate a subset of items instantiated by Repeater one after another in Qt QML?

Tags: qt, animation, timer, qml, repeater

Is there a standard QML component using which several items created in Repeater can be animated one after the other with some delay (i.e. not simultaneously)?
So far I could only come up with a Timer based solution like below:

```
import QtQuick 6.3

Item {
    width: 600; height: 400

    Row {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 5
        Repeater {
            id: _repeater
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: 10
            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: _rect
                width: 50; height: 50
                color: "green"
                function animate() {_anim.start()}
                SequentialAnimation {
                    id: _anim
                    NumberAnimation {target: _rect; property: "height"; from: 50; to: 150}
                    NumberAnimation {target: _rect; property: "height"; from: 150; to: 50}
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Timer {
        id: _timer
        property var indexes
        repeat: true
        interval: 150
        onTriggered: {
            if (indexes.length !== 0) {
                 _repeater.itemAt(indexes.shift()).animate()
            } else
                stop()
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            _timer.indexes = [1, 2, 3, 4]
            _timer.start() 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't think of any built-in that would do what you describe, what you have looks pretty much like what I would do if faced w/ the same problem. If you want to avoid a timer you could perhaps use signals/slots instead. For example, have the delegate _rect emit a signal (perhaps w/ its index) when its animation is complete, and have some orchestrator catch that signal and kick off the next delegate's animation.

Comment: Alternatively, you could also just have some `property int activeAnimationIndex`, have a binding in the delegates to run their animation if their index matches that property, and increment the `activeAnimationIndex` as needed.

Comment: @dabbler thanks. this gives me some confidence that what I'm doing is not completely wrong and that I'm not missing an obvious solution

Comment: It's only _completely_ wrong if it doesn't work :P -- I'd say you're on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Timeline](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6.2/qml-qtquick-timeline-timeline.html#animations-prop) for that, this is a small example:

```js
    import QtQuick
    import QtQuick.Timeline
    import QtQuick.Controls
    
    Window {
        width: 500
        height: 400
        visible: true
    
        Component {
            id: keyframeComponent
            KeyframeGroup {
                property int startFrame: 0
                property int endFrame: 0
                property int startValue: 0
                property: "height"
                Keyframe { frame: startFrame; value: startValue }
                Keyframe { frame: (startFrame + endFrame) / 2; value: 300 }
                Keyframe { frame: endFrame; value: startValue }
            }
        }
    
        Row {
            width: parent.width
            height: 300
            spacing: 1
            Repeater {
                model: 10
                Rectangle {
                    id: rect
                    width: 49
                    height: Math.round(Math.random() * parent.height)
                    color: "orange"
                    Component.onCompleted: {
                        var startFrame = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        var endFrame = Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
                        if(startFrame > endFrame)
                        {
                            var temp = endFrame;
                            endFrame = startFrame;
                            startFrame = temp;
                        }
                        var group = keyframeComponent.createObject(timelineAnimation, {
                                                                       startFrame: startFrame,
                                                                       endFrame: endFrame,
                                                                       startValue: rect.height,
                                                                       target: rect });
                        timeline.keyframeGroups.push(group);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        Button {
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            text: "Start"
            onClicked: {
                timelineAnimation.start();
            }
        }
    
        Timeline {
            id: timeline
            startFrame: 0
            endFrame: 100
            enabled: true
    
            animations: [
                TimelineAnimation {
                    duration: 1000;
                    from: 0;
                    to: 100;
                    running: false;
                    id: timelineAnimation
                }
            ]
            keyframeGroups: []
        }
    }
```

Here I create `KeyframeGroup` dynamically but you can create that statically of course.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT Again]

You can use `PauseAnimation` to introduce a delay.

The other change is for each delegate, I expose a callback function so that the delegate's animation can be accessed outside of the delegate.

The `MouseArea` merely uses the callback function to trigger whichever delegate it needs to animate and with whatever delay.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    id: page
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    property var animateFuncs: ([ ])
    Repeater {
        model: 10
        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: _rect
            border.color: "white"
            color: "green"
            x: index * 60 + 50
            y: 50
            width: 50
            height: 50
            SequentialAnimation {
                id: anim
                property int delay
                PauseAnimation {duration: anim.delay}
                NumberAnimation {target: _rect; property: "height"; from: 50; to: 150}
                NumberAnimation {target: _rect; property: "height"; from: 150; to: 50}
            }
            function animateWithDelay(delay) {
                anim.delay = delay;
                anim.start();
            }
            Component.onCompleted: animateFuncs[index] = animateWithDelay
        }
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
             let pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
             animateFuncs[pick](0);
             animateFuncs[pick+1](300);
             animateFuncs[pick+2](600);
             animateFuncs[pick+3](900);
             animateFuncs[pick+4](1200);
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: I didn’t know of such a possibility. However in your example all items are animated, while I need animate only a subgroup which can be specified at runtime

Comment: I see, I will update the answer accordingly, but, it would be helpful for you to explain the UI/UX in which you nominate the subgroup to be animated.

Comment: Why didn't you use [PauseAnimation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-pauseanimation.html)?

Comment: Thanks, @SMR I replaced `NumberAnimation` delay-hack with `PauseAnimation` as you suggested. It makes the answer much better, thanks.